# Can Streamsets Data Collector CDC read from and write to multiple tables?

Tags: database, cdc, data-collection, streamsets

I have a MSSQL database whose structure is replicated over a Postgres database.
I've enabled CDC in MSSQL and I've used the SQL Server CDC Client in StreamSets Data Collector to listen for changes in that db's tables.

But I can't find a way to write to the same tables in Postgres.

For example I have 3 tables in MSSQL:
tableA, tableB, tableC. Same tables I have in Postgres.
I insert data into tableA and tableC. I want those changes to be replicated over Postgres.

In StreamSets DC, in order to write to Postgres, I'm using JDBC Producer and in the Table Name field I've specified: ${record:attributes('jdbc.tables')}.

Doing this, the data will be read from tableA_CT, tableB_CT, tableC_CT. Tables created by MSSQL when you enable the CDC option. So I'll end up with those table names in the ${record:attribute('jdbc.tables')}.

Is there a way to write to Postgres in the same tables as in MSSQL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cut the `_CT` suffix off the `jdbc.tables` attribute by using an [Expression Evaluator](https://streamsets.com/documentation/datacollector/latest/help/index.html#datacollector/UserGuide/Processors/Expression.html#concept_zm2_pp3_wq) with a **Header Attribute Expression** of:

```
${str:isNullOrEmpty(record:attribute('jdbc.tables')) ? '' : 
  str:substring(record:attribute('jdbc.tables'), 0, 
    str:length(record:attribute('jdbc.tables')) - 3)}
```

Note - the `str:isNullOrEmpty` test is a workaround for [SDC-9269](https://issues.streamsets.com/browse/SDC-9269).

Comment: Thanks ! I did that already. Was wondering if there was a more direct solution.

Comment: Not as far as I know - the _CT suffix is in the data that arrives from SQL Server, so it's what we pass on.

Answer (score 0):

The following expression provides the original table name

```
${record:attribute('jdbc.cdc.source_name')}
```

If you are looking for the original table schema name then you can use

```
${record:attribute('jdbc.cdc.source_schema_name')}
```